# How to find out depth buffer resolution in OpenGL ES?

Tags: c#, opengl-es, depth-buffer, qualcomm

I was using the following code to produce depth values:

```
sealed class GL24: iDepthValues
{
    const double mul = 2.0 / 0xFFFFFF;
    float iDepthValues.value( int index )
    {
        // Have no idea why "+2", but without the +2 the very first layer is depth-clipped out on Linux.
        return (float)( 1.0 - ( index + 2 ) * mul );
    }
}
```

It was not good enough on Adreno 330 inside Qualcomm MSM8974 Snapdragon 800. The sequential values of the `index` resulted in unwanted depth clipping.

I’ve increased the multiplier to `16.0 / 0xFFFFFF` and it started to work. Apparently, the GPU doesn’t have 24 bits for the depth, only 21. While I made it work, this left me wondering — is there a way to make that code reliable on other GPUs as well? I.e. how to query the real depth buffer resolution of the actual hardware?

P.S. I don’t use any desktop managers, the GPU is initialized with DRM, KMS, and EGL. The EGL config I’m picking says “24 bits depth”. The GPU driver is Mesa, the OS is Alpine Linux, kernel version 5.14.2. I’m using GLES 2.0 GPU API.